# php execute wget and python script

Tags: php, execute

I try to execute a command "wget" to download a file on my server A and then execute a python who will scrypt argument in this file.

My script:

```
switch ($_POST["parse"]) {
    case 'parse1':
        shell_exec("wget http://localhost/".$file_path);
        shell_exec("python /opt/lampp/htdocs/mysite/api/scripts/script_parse.py  ".$file_path." 1");
        echo $file_path;
        break;

    default:
        echo "no";
        break;
}
```

However (I'm with local xampp under debian), the file is not downloaded and I have a page that loads into space when I try to execute the script (with or without file) but that does nothing .

So I'm looking since last night but I can not.

Besides, I like to avoid that the page load until the end of script execution.

Comment: How is this a Python question actually ?

Comment: The wget not work and python command also.

Comment: And ? How is this a Python question ? As long as your first shell_exec call fails, you'd have the very same problem on the second one whatever the language used for implementation. The fact that it's written in Python is totally irrelevant to your question.

Comment: The problem is not the execution of the python script but the first "wget" who do not download anything, I tried to isolate the shell_exec for the execution of the python script but it ca not simply market (infinite loading).

Comment: The problem is probably PHP configuration. Shell execution can lead to various system and privacy violations and this is why it can be disabled in cfg. http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php You should consider preparing any sort of error handling. In current state you have no idea what is happening inside. Also, remove python and wget tags, as it is not relevant.

Comment: "The problem is not the execution of the python script but the first "wget"" : yes, just what I said : it has nothing to do with Python.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `shell_exec()` and `wget` to download the file, use "file_get_contents()`. [It supports both the HTTP and the HTTPS protocols](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), among many others, and it'll also give you an informative error message if downloading fails.

You will also need to add some error handling to your code, as stated in the comment by Arek. Since that is the only way you can properly handle the situations where something goes wrong, and they will. Not only for your sake, to make it easier to detect and debug, but also for your users.

Read the PHP manual, find out what values the different functions return in case of errors, and check against these. If any of the functions does return an erroneous value, then show an error message to the user and abort the rest of business logic (the stuff your code is really meant to do).